# Template for human readable date time?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, go-templates

`{{ now }}` gives: `2019-05-30 04:40:35.847147175 +0000 UTC m=+1983611.179295260`

and I would like to make this more human readable by grabbing the first 2 and joining = `2019-05-30-04:40:35.847147175`.

How can this be done?

Failed attempt:

```
time: {{ now || splitList " " | (not sure how to slice first 2) | join "-" }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look through the whole list of [Sprig date functions](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/date.html), where [Sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/) is a library of Go template functions that is included in Helm.

In particular you probably want the `date` function, which formats a `time.Time` value using a Go format string.  As the linked documentation says:

> ...take this as the base date: `Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006`  Write it in the format you want.

So try something like

```
{{ now | date "2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000" }}
```

The extended examples for the Go [`(*time.Time).Format`](https://godoc.org/time#ex-Time-Format) function are probably relevant here too; for example, `15:04:05.999999` should drop trailing zeros if that's what you want.